# CakePHP doesn't fill the parent field in add.ctp automatically

Tags: php, cakephp, view

I've created a Tree structure following [this example](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/tree.html).
The nodes are added successfully but the parent field is empty and I can't add a child to any node using the add.ctp view!
How can I fill this field with category names already exist in table? Shouldn't it load them automatically? As you see in the picture the Parent field is empty!

[image]

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Cakephp won't fill that field automatically, you will have to do it depending on your needs, maybe it is enough with: `$this->Category->find('list');`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your field in form is parent_id you should have $parents aviable in the view. So propably in Category add action you should do:

```
 $parents = $this->Category->Parent->find('list');
 $this->set(compact('parents'));
```

notice that `$this->Category->Parent` would only work if you have proper relation set in the Category model...

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but I have a similar problem.

When I use $this->set(compact('parents')); it works, but if I use another variable name, like 'parentLabels' it does not seem to work, is 'parents' a matter of convention?

Comment: yes this is a convention. If you put in select form field "foo_id" it will be filled by variable foos, but you can alvays override it wit "options" parameter (see http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html)

Comment: If I would want to do this from the model, how do I achieve the same results? That is, have some function in the model that loads all the "parents" and saves them to the model.

Comment: It depends from which model you want to do it, but it is more or less the same, you just need to omit the model name, So in Category model:  `$parents = $this->Parent->find('all');` ; Is this helpfull ?

Comment: Darn it !! Thanks ! I forgot(already faced this issue in one of my previous projects on Cake) that the variable name should match the field name... I baked the controller and the variable was named as `$parentStuffs` in controller... i just had to rename the variable to `$parents`... Seems it will take me some more time to get along with CakePHP's conventions... or I think I should stop baking controllers... hope this is fixed in Cake 3, haven't used it yet.